# How to change separator in a new file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file `marks.txt` that looks like this separated by spaces.

```
1)  Amit    Physics  80
2)  Rahul   Maths    90
3)  Shyam   Biology  87
4)  Kedar   English  85
5)  Hari    History  89
```

I want to convert the separator into ",".
The desired output is this

```
1),Amit,Physics,80
2),Rahul,Maths,90
3),Shyam,Biology,87
4),Kedar,English,85
5),Hari,History,89
```

I found out this can be done by

```
awk '$1=$1' FS=" " OFS="," marks.txt
```

However I don't understand what `'$1=$1'` means.
Also, when I type

```
awk '{print}' FS=" " OFS=":" marks.txt>test
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}1' marks.txt >test
```

nothing changes. Why? Thank you very much.

Comment: Be careful with `$1 = $1` - you are assigning the first field to itself (causing the line to be reformatted, as explained in the answers) and then evaluating the first field as a condition. If the first field was `0` then the condition would be false and the line would not be printed. The safe way is `{ $1 = $1 } 1`, where `1` is a separate condition that is always true.

Comment: Aha I see, putting $1 = $1 into action{} also works! thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could verify this by yourself by printing lines before and after for testing for it.

```
awk '{print "BEFORE line-->" $0;$1=$1;print "AFTER line-->" $0}' FS=" " OFS=","  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
BEFORE line-->1)  Amit    Physics  80
AFTER line-->1),Amit,Physics,80
BEFORE line-->2)  Rahul   Maths    90
AFTER line-->2),Rahul,Maths,90
BEFORE line-->3)  Shyam   Biology  87
AFTER line-->3),Shyam,Biology,87
BEFORE line-->4)  Kedar   English  85
AFTER line-->4),Kedar,English,85
BEFORE line-->5)  Hari    History  89
AFTER line-->5),Hari,History,89
```

By this we could see that `$1=$1` re-evaluate value of it and changes whole line's value accordingly.

***More explanation from comments:***
thing is if you re-initiate $1 or $2 or any field whole line be re-evaluated or re-read and it will apply OFS new value then. We write it $1 we could write it $2 eg--> `awk '$2=$2' FS=" " OFS="," Input_file`

Comment: I see! But why reanlalyze only the first field $1? Does $1 represent the whole line? Thank you very much.

Comment: @SuminKim, thing is if you re-initiate `$1` or `$2` or any field whole line be re-evaluated or re-read and it will apply `OFS` new value then. We write it `$1` we could write it `$2` eg--> `awk '$2=$2' FS=" " OFS=","  Input_file`

Comment: Aha I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: That explanation should go into the answer, as the example just demonstrates what the OP has already seen.

Comment: @TomFenech, sure added it now in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps to see it concretely explained in the manual, you can see it here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html

> Finally, there are times when it is convenient to force awk to rebuild
>   the entire record, using the current values of the fields and OFS. To
>   do this, use the seemingly innocuous assignment:
>
> ```
> $1 = $1   # force record to be reconstituted 
> print $0  # or whatever else with $0
> ```
>
> This forces awk to rebuild the record. It does help to
>   add a comment, as we’ve shown here.

I can't help but note that the author's admonition to include a comment would have helped you here!

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `$1=$1` is what causes the fields to be reanalyzed. Without it, Awk simply passes on input to output.